# Invalid type "string | undefined" of template literal expression even though I safely use literals

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I have a simple component that loops out buttons. TS fails build where I call this loop with error

```
17:60  Error: Invalid type "string | undefined" of template literal expression.
```

I call the function in my JSX return like this

```
  {customerList && customerList as JSX.Element[]}
```

There are no template literals in the fil I loop out buttons in, so I don't think the issue is there. But here is the full file (without imports and exports)

```
const HiglightedCustomers = ({ customers, title }: { customers: Kunder[], title : string }) => {
  const CustomerTemplate = ({customer}:{customer: Kunder}) => {
    const {url, name} = customer
    return <div className="p-2">
        <Button href={url || "#"} externalLink={true} variant="bg-primary-light-pink">{name}</Button>
        </div>
  }
    const customerList = customers?.map((customer) => <CustomerTemplate key={customer.id} customer={customer} />);

    return (
    <div className="border bg-red-500 ">
      <h2 className="text-3xl  text-center">{title}</h2>
      <div className="flex max-w-3xl pt-3 flex-wrap justify-center">
      {customerList && customerList as JSX.Element[]}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Inside my -component I use template literals. But I do this in a way that to me seems safe. I have default values for my props and functions that work just fine even if the template literals are undefines

My button file

```
import { z } from 'zod';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { BgColorVariants } from '@/lib/commonTypes';

type Variant = z.infer<typeof BgColorVariants>;

const ButtonSchema = z.object({
  variant: BgColorVariants.optional(),
  children: z.string(),
  link: z.boolean().optional(), 
  externalLink: z.boolean().optional(),
  href: z.string().optional(),
});

type ButtonProps = z.infer<typeof ButtonSchema>;

const Button = ({ variant = 'bg-black', externalLink = false, href, children,...rest }: ButtonProps) => {
  const textColor = ({variant}:{variant: Variant}) => {
    // Returner svart tekst på bakgrunner som krever svart tekst, ellers svart tekst 
    if(variant === "bg-primary-light-pink"){
      return "text-black "
    }
    else {
      return "text-white group-hover:text-black"
    }
  }
  
  const ButtonContent = () => {
    const buttonStyle = `relative z-10 inline-flex items-center justify-center h-full w-full rounded py-2 px-3 ${textColor({ variant }) || ''} ${variant} border border-black group-hover:bg-primary-pink  group-hover:border-black group-hover:border-w`
    const shadowBox = "absolute top-[0.15em] left-[0.15em] h-full w-full group-hover:bg-black bg-transparent rounded py-2 px-3 z-0 group-hover:border-black group-hover:border "
    return (
      <div className="relative inline-block group">
        <div className={shadowBox}></div>
        <div className={buttonStyle}>{children}</div>
      </div>
    )
  };

  return (
    <>
      {href && !externalLink && <Link  href={href}><ButtonContent /></Link> }
      {href && externalLink && <a href={href} rel="external nofollow"><ButtonContent /></a> }
      {!href && <button ><ButtonContent /></button>}
      </>
  );
};
```

I'm getting to my witts end and have been trying to debug this for days. Any suggestions on how I can solve this are very much welcome.

Answer (score 0):

`customerList` is a component, so it needs to be capitalized, such as `Customerlist`.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue, "Invalid type'string | undefined' of template literal expression," is due to the way TypeScript handles optional properties during type checking. It happens specifically in the line when you're attempting to render the **customerList**:

```
customerList as JSX.Element && customerList
```

The problem is in the manner you created **customerList** and used the optional chaining operator (?) on the **customers** array. Although it can produce a union type with undefined in the expression, the optional chaining operator enables safe access to properties that might be undefined or null.

Before mapping customers to build the **customerList**, use Array.isArray() to determine if **customers** are an array.

Return an empty array to guarantee that the resultant customerList is of type JSX if **customers** is not an array (undefined).Element[].